# Getting my dynamic php array to js

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, loops

Here's what I got

```
$x=$ris;
while ($x<$rie){
     array_push($array, pg_fetch_result($result,$x,0));
     $x=$x+1;
}
```

So I'm just pushing lot's of values from a column to $array. I want to transmit the data in this array to a js array. So here's what's happening:

```
  <script>
  var temp = <?php echo json_encode($rie-$ris); ?>;
  var temp2=0;
  var jarray = [];
  while (temp2<temp)
  {
       jarray.push(<?php echo json_encode($array[temp2]); ?>);
       temp2++;
  }
  console.log(jarray)
  </script>
```

Whenever I try to print anything out, jarray has nothing in it, which leads me to think that this

```
       jarray.push(<?php echo json_encode($array[temp2]); ?>);
```

line is messed up. It's probably because I'm trying to reference a js variable in a php echo. The problem is I'm trying to make a while loop to just copy the array over, but in js, I'm incrementing a js var, so how can I possibly do this?

Comment: Why not first printing $array to javascript with `json_encode`, then not to use any php ?

Comment: In my opinion, you are better off sending the whole thing as a string to Javascript, and split it there.  What you're doing is creating an object in one place, then recreating the exact same object using the same method elsewhere.  Since you have to do that second step anyway, why bother the first time?

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu, So you mean during the while loop where I'm array_pushing? If so, how can I use json_encode if I can't set a js var value to it?

Comment: @john No. I meant use sth like `var myArray = <?php json_encode($array) ?>` before while. Then use `myArray` inside the while loop like myArray[temp2]``;

Comment: Your issue with `jarray.push(<?php echo json_encode($array[temp2]); ?>);` is basic php/JavaScript 101. Php is parsed server side **before** page load. JavaScript is parsed client side **after** page load. So when the JavaScript is running, the php is already parsed, so it won't change/accept your js values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code. First [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your php array and then [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in js after that while loop.

```
<script>
  var temp = <?php echo json_encode($rie-$ris); ?>;
  var temp2=0;
  var jarray = [];
  var arr = '<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>';
  var arr_p = JSON.parse(arr);
  while (temp2<temp)
  {
       jarray.push(arr_p[temp2]);
       temp2++;
  }
  console.log(jarray)
</script>
```